# Using Canvas in a Blazor server application and running a function on load

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server for a project and I want to be able to use Html5 canvas for an animation.
I did the following

1. Added my script path to the body section of _Host.cshtml ()
2. created a component that looks like this. This holds the canvas

   ```
        @page "/MyPage"
        @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;


        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CallJsMethod">Call Js Method</button>

         <div class="text-center py-5">
             <canvas id="canvas" class="border" width="500px" ondrop="drop(event, element)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></canvas>
         </div>

        @code {

            private async Task CallJsMethod()
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("");
            }

        }
   ```

Here is my onload code I have in my javascript file

```
        window.onload = function () {
            var initX = canvas.width / 2;
            var initY = 0;
            circleList.forEach(function (element) {
                initY = initY + parseInt(element.score) + 10;
                var circleObject = {
                    centerX: initX,
                    centerY: initY,
                    radius: parseInt(element.score),
                    draging: false,
                    overlapMark: false,
                    subject: element.subject,
                }
                initY = initY + parseInt(element.score) + 20;
                circleData.push(circleObject);
            });
            drawAll();
        }
```

I want to be able to call this window.onload when the Blazor component above loads so that I can see my Canvas. I tried changing the window.onload to a function name
like TestMe but no luck.

When I look at the console section of my page all i see is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

In my Javascript file (script.js), I am doing this

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

This works well when I use visual studio code.

How do I make my canvas work in a Blazor server application and load my main function?

Comment: Everything in JavaScript should be happening within the `load` Event. Where is `circleList`?

Comment: circleList exist in the script.js file.

Comment: If that file uses `window.onload` you are overwriting it. You should get into the practice of using `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* code here */})`, instead. Note that your variables must be scoped above the load Events for them to be accessible to other pages.

Comment: circleList is an array of object which is been called within window.onload.  My question is how do I call this in a Blazor application. I am not sure you are understanding my question. Use addEventListener for what? Use it to replace window.onload?  I am not understanding you sorry.

Comment: Yes, you can only have one `onload` Event on the window with the easy assignment style of listener, since assignment overwrites. You can, however store into a variable as an unexecuted function that you execute immediately within your overwritten `onload`, but I would use `addEventListener('load', ()=>{})` instead.